# How come it's called criss-crossed?

Tags: word-meaning

Criss means "a wooden stand with a curved top on which crest tiles are shaped." But when we combine "criss" and "crossed" (criss-crossed) it means "to move or exist in a pattern of lines crossing something or each other." Why is that? It seems that with this combination "criss" has lost its original meaning. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of [*crisscross*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crisscross) has nothing to do with the word [*criss*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criss).

From the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/crisscross#etymonline_v_364):

> **crisscross (n.)**
> also *criss-cross*, 1833, "a checked pattern in cloth," 1848, "a crossing or intersection," from Middle English *crist(s)-crosse* (early 15c.), earlier *Cristes-cros* (c. 1200) "the Cross of Christ," also "the sign of the cross," from late 14c. often "referring to the mark of a cross formerly written before the alphabet in hornbooks. The mark itself stood for the phrase *Christ-cross me speed* ('May Christ's cross give me success'), a formula said before reciting the alphabet" [Barnhart]. It has long been used without awareness of its origin.
>
> > How long agoo lerned ye, 'Crist crosse me spede!'
> > Have ye no more lernyd of youre a b c,
> > [Lydgate, "The Prohemy of a Marriage Betwix an Olde Man and a Yonge Wife," c. 1475]
>
> It is attested from 1860 as an old name for tic-tac-toe. As an adjective, by 1846. As a verb, by 1818.

Comment: Thank you all so very much for your detailed explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Criss-cross is an example of "ablaut-reduplication" the word is doubled with a change in vowel sound. Other examples of this include "zig-zag", "pitter-patter", "flip-flop"  Notice that the first sound tends to be a high vowel like /i/ and the second is a low vowel like /a/

This reduplication was, no doubt, influenced by "Christ-cross", with the loss of the "t" to conform with the reduplication and for euphony.